# Minimizing Pairwise Sums

Tags: elementary-number-theory, optimization

> Assume we have five positive integers summing to $2010$. Call them $v, w, x, y, z.$ Look at the sums $v+w$, $w+x$, $x+y$, and $y+z$. What is the smallest possible value of the largest sum?

$\textbf{What I Did:}$

I thought that all five pairs must sum to $4020$, and that the maximum of the pairs is minimized when the pairs are as close to each other as possible. Thus, I took $4020$ divided by $5$ and got $804$ as my answer.

$\textbf{Where I'm Stuck:}$

The answer is $671$, and I have no idea how to obtain it. I would appreciate anyone who could illuminate me on this.

Comment: There are 10 (unordered) pairs of 5 numbers, but I don't see how summing all the pairs is helpful. But something is wrong here. If the two largest numbers sum to 671, the three remaining numbers must sum to 1339, so they have a mean of 446⅓, and they can't all be less than the smaller of the two numbers summing to 671.

Comment: Do we have any more information? Are the numbers all supposed to be different, or are repetitions permitted?

Comment: @PM2Ring indeed, the largest two numbers would have to be each at least 447. Something is wrong.

Comment: Something is very wrong. John, what makes you think the answer is $671$? Where did you see this question? Where did you see the answer?

Comment: @PM2Ring So sorry, there is an extra stipulation in the problem I forgot to add. I'm recalling the problem from memory and forgot to add that. I have edited the statement now. Apologies to any confusion this may have caused all of you.

Answer (score 2):

Introduce variable $u$ to represent the largest sum.  The problem is to minimize $u$ subject to linear constraints
\begin{align}
v + w + x + y + z &= 2010 \label1\tag1 \\
u - v - w &\ge 0 \label2\tag2 \\
u - w - x &\ge 0 \label3\tag3 \\
u - x - y &\ge 0 \label4\tag4 \\
u - y - z &\ge 0 \label5\tag5 \\
v &\ge 1 \label6\tag6 \\
w &\ge 1 \label7\tag7 \\
x &\ge 1 \label8\tag8 \\
y &\ge 1 \label9\tag9 \\
z &\ge 1 \label{10}\tag{10}
\end{align}
If you ignore the integrality restriction, an optimal solution is
$$(u,v,w,x,y,z)=(670+1/3,669+1/3,1,669+1/3,1,669+1/3).$$
To certify optimality, sum constraints \eqref{1}, \eqref{2}, \eqref{3}, \eqref{5}, and \eqref{7}, yielding
$3u\ge 2011$,
which implies that $u \ge 670+1/3$ and hence $u \ge 671$ for integer $u$.  To attain this lower bound, take integer solution
$$(u,v,w,x,y,z)=(671,670,1,670,1,668).$$